# Working with Azure notification hub using IONIC 3

Tags: firebase, azure, ionic-framework, push-notification, ionic3

We are currently using azure notification hub which allows us to work with both APN and GCM/FCM. Push notification functionality works properly with our current native apps (both android and iOS).

Now we are developing new apps using IONIC 3 and now trying to implement push notification in the same. There are many articles we have gone through. Some of them are using either ionic 1 or ionic 2. Few are using deprecated packages which are not supported on IONIC 3.

Backend developers have used the variant where the notification hub is the central point for device registrations. Devices are registered with the notification hub directly, rather than through our back-end. The first thing we are trying to achieve is registering our devices with notification hub when app is installed on device and running it for the first time. We are not finding a way to do it. We tried using couple of packages available but it did not work. We already have created project in firebase. Offical website has [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/notification-hubs/) for all applications excpet ionic/cordova. Any suggestions will be helpful for implementing it.

Answer (score 2):

I created an Ionic 3 sample in the [Azure Notification Hubs Samples](https://github.com/Azure/azure-notificationhubs-samples/tree/master/Ionic) repository a few months ago. It uses a third-party Cordova plugin to manage registration. The plugin is active, I've made a couple of contributions and they were accepted by the plugin author.

I'm working on an Ionic 4 sample, which I'll publish in the same repo, but Capacitor has a problem with the Cordova plugin and I've not spent enough time trying to figure it out. I'll try to do so soon.

Comment: Were you able to get it running with Ionic 4 + Capacitor? We are currently thinking about using Azure Notification Hubs for our Ionic 4 app, but I was not able to find any working samples. Would be nice if you could share what you found out. Thanks!

Comment: I'm working on the Ionic 4/Capacitor version now. I got the plugin working with Capacitor and registration works, but I'm not getting notifications. I'll keep working on it and should have something soon.

Comment: here's an article I published with some details: https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/Azure-Developer-Community-Blog/Using-Azure-Notification-Hubs-in-Apache-Cordova-and-Ionic-Apps/ba-p/1056685.